# Is it possible to switch Tabs in JavaFx?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I just simply want to change my tabs I created with TabPane from JavaFx with code. I want a Button who switch the Tab when I press. I search for a Function like:`tabpane.selectTab(index)`
Have anyone a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the selection model first

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TabPane.html#getSelectionModel--

And then you can select a tab.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SingleSelectionModel.html#select-int-

There are other ways to select than by index, read the docs in 2nd link.

`tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(index);`

note, most or all selections in javaFX seem to use a selectionModel.

Comment: Thank you very much :D